# Haskell Lens: Prism over maybes

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have those lenses:

```
getB :: Lens' A (Maybe B) 

getC :: Prism' B C
```

How can I extract a `Maybe C` from an A?
The best I could find:

```
case A ^. getB of
    Just b -> b ^? getC
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Anything more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```hs
_Just :: Prism' (Maybe a) a
```

The `_Just` prism will get you the value out of a `Maybe`.

```hs
a ^? getB . _Just . getC
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `Maybe`'s `Traversable` instance, which gets the value inside the `Just` if there is one.

```hs
-- traverse :: Traversal' (Maybe a) a
a ^? getB . traverse . getC
```